# Cannot find ssl libraries when configuring stunnel

Tags: ssl, rhel5, stunnel

I am using RHEL 5.6 and trying to install stunnel with the 'xforwardfor' patch from haproxy to get a setup similar to this (older) post: http://www.buro9.com/blog/2009/12/07/installing-haproxy-load-balance-http-and-https/

When I run ./configure I get the following error:

```
*snip*
configure: **************************************** SSL
checking for SSL directory... Not found

Couldn't find your SSL library installation dir
Use --with-ssl option to fix this problem
```

From the [stunnel documentation](http://www.onsight.com/faq/stunnel/stunnel-faq-8.html) I need to pass a directory that has the ssl libraries (assuming libssl.so ? ) as well as a 'certs' directory.

I've tried creating a /etc/openssl directory with a 'certs' directory and a symlink to `/lib64/libssl.so.6` but that didn't work.

What other libraries would I need ?

**Update**

From the config.log:

It was created by stunnel configure 4.32, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.61.  Invocation command line was

```
$ ./configure --with-ssl=/lib64

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 2.6.18-238.12.1.el5
uname -s = Linux
* snip *
configure:23977: **************************************** SSL
configure:23996: checking for SSL directory
configure:24019: result: Not found
```

And running `ls /lib64 | grep ssl`:

```
$ ls -l /lib64 | grep ssl
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  315032 Dec  7  2010 libssl.so.0.9.8e
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 Jul 13 18:48 libssl.so.6 -> libssl.so.0.9.8e
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing you don't have `openssl-devel` installed.

Here is the stunnel-4.42 `configure` output I got on a RHEL5.6 server:

```
**************************************** SSL
checking for SSL directory... /usr/
checking for obsolete RSAref library... no
checking /usr//include/openssl/engine.h usability... yes
checking /usr//include/openssl/engine.h presence... yes
checking for /usr//include/openssl/engine.h... yes
```

The function `check_ssl_dir` in `configure` is looking for `/usr/include/openssl/ssl.h` which is part of `openssl-devel`.

**Do not** pass any options to configure, do any directory creation, or make any symlinks.

Comment: I was just coming to post this exact answer. I just found out about the openssl-devel package. Thanks!

Comment: Good Answer. I was encountering a similar same error on Ubuntu and Linux Mint and I found that installing the 'libssl-dev' package helped to fix this error.

Answer (score 1):

The certificates live in */etc/openssl* and 64 bit software libraries in */lib64*. You should not mix those. Assuming that you are on a 64 bit platform and the library exists in /lib64, try this:

```
./configure --with-ssl=/lib64
```

...and if it does not work, post the relevant part of "config.log" file to assist you further.

Comment: Thanks for the response. /etc/openssl doesn't exist on my platform (but openssl is installed). The stunnel link states that the ssl library directory should have the 'certs' directory...why is it a bad idea to mix them using symlinks? I added my config.log and ssl-related /lib64 libraries.

Answer (score 0):

On debian you have to install `libssl-dev` than you can build stunnel.